# How to format JFXTextField to add spaces on every two characters?

Tags: javafx, formatting, textfield, jfoenix

Hi I m trying to add a space formating fonctionality to my textfield (I m using JFoenix) my goal is to write `100000`   as `10 00 00` and `1000000` as `1 00 00 00`

here is my attempt but my result is reverse because the caret is losing position.

```
public static void setup(JFXTextField textField) {
    textField.setOnKeyReleased(value->{
         String entredText = textField.getText();
         String noSpaced = entredText.replaceAll("\\s+","");
         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
         for (int i = 0; i < noSpaced.length(); i++) {
             builder.append(noSpaced.charAt(i));
             if (i%2==0) {
                 builder.append(" ");
             }
         }
         textField.setText(builder.toString());
      });
}
```

for test the issues that I m facing here are : to much spaces and the writing is reversed

thanks to Armel Sahamene answer we have the spacing issue fixed but not the reversing one

123456 should be 12 34 56 but the result is 65 43 21

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions are already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732047/how-to-apply-mask-formatting-to-textfield).

For your case I would recommend to use [MaskField](https://github.com/vas7n/VAMaskField).

Comment: i m using Jfoenix maskfield is great but not a desired solution

Answer (score 1):

your format depends on the length of the noSpaced string. so fix your if condition like this:

```
public static void setup(JFXTextField textField) {
textField.setOnKeyReleased(value->{
     String entredText = textField.getText();
     String noSpaced = entredText.replaceAll("\\s+","");
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     for (int i = 0; i < noSpaced.length(); i++) {
         builder.append(noSpaced.charAt(i));
         if ((i % 2 == 0 && noSpaced.length() % 2 == 1) || (i % 2 == 1 && noSpaced.length() % 2 == 0)) {
             builder.append(" ");
         }
     }
     textField.setText(builder.toString());
  });
```

}

Comment: the issue here is there is still the reversed format issue
try to write 123987  that should be 12 39 87  but you will get 78 93 21 How to fix this ? knowing is due to the caret position